# Получить объект из базы данных

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Есть одна база данных и 3 таблицы (**My Task, Family Task, In Process**), мне нужно по id получать объект(задачу) из базы данных и перемещать его в таблицу **My Task** и **In Process**.

У меня есть код для того, чтобы курсором проходить по всей базе, получать объекты и записывать их в listview

```
sqlDB = famDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor c = sqlDB.query(famDBHelper.FAM_TABLE_NAME, null,
        null, null,
        null, null, null);

if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {

        int idColIndex = c.getColumnIndex(famDBHelper.FAM_COLUMN_ID);
        int topicColIndex = c.getColumnIndex(famDBHelper.FAM_COLUMN_TOPIC);
        int contentColIndex = c.getColumnIndex(famDBHelper.FAM_COLUMN_CONTENT);
        int deadlineColIndex = c.getColumnIndex(famDBHelper.FAM_COLUMN_DEADLINE);

        famTask.add(new FamilyTask(c.getString(topicColIndex),
                c.getString(contentColIndex),
                c.getString(deadlineColIndex), c.getString(idColIndex)));

        familyTaskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Ура, все хорошо!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } while (c.moveToNext());
} else
    c.close();

famDBHelper.close();
```

А так же код для вставки в базу данных

```
sqlDB = famDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
cv = new ContentValues();

cv.put(ComDBHelper.FAM_COLUMN_TOPIC, fam_topic_et.getText().toString());
cv.put(ComDBHelper.FAM_COLUMN_CONTENT, fam_content_et.getText().toString());
cv.put(ComDBHelper.FAM_COLUMN_DEADLINE, fam_deadline_et.getText().toString());

id = String.valueOf(sqlDB.insert(famDBHelper.FAM_TABLE_NAME, null, cv));
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Успешно! rowID: " + id,
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

famDBHelper.close();
```

Как мне вытащить один единственный объект из базы данных по id, который мне известен и вставлять в другие таблицы - не имею ни малейшего понятия. Буду благодарна за любую подсказку/помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Четвертый параметр это selectionArgs.
Попробуйте что-то типа этого:

```
Cursor c = famDBHelper.query(famDBHelper.FAM_TABLE_NAME, null,
        null, new String[]{"id=1"},
        null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Я брала всю информация не из базы данных, а из item'a ListView:

```
String topic = familyTaskAdapter.getItem(position).getFam_task_topic();
String content = familyTaskAdapter.getItem(position).getFam_task_content();
String deadline = familyTaskAdapter.getItem(position).getFam_deadline();
```

Затем открывала базу данных и записывала в две другие таблицы данные из первой:

```
sqLiteDatabase = comDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

contentValues.put(ComDBHelper.MY_COLUMN_TOPIC, topic);
contentValues.put(ComDBHelper.MY_COLUMN_CONTENT, content);
contentValues.put(ComDBHelper.MY_COLUMN_DEADLINE, deadline);

sqLiteDatabase.insert(ComDBHelper.MY_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

contentValues.put(ComDBHelper.IP_COLUMN_TOPIC, topic);
contentValues.put(ComDBHelper.IP_COLUMN_CONTENT, content);
contentValues.put(ComDBHelper.IP_COLUMN_DEADLINE, deadline);

sqLiteDatabase.insert(ComDBHelper.IP_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

comDBHelper.close();
```

Далее удаляла задачу из таблицы:

```
sqLiteDatabase = comDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

int id = Integer.parseInt(familyTaskAdapter.getItem(position).getFam_task_num());
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + ComDBHelper.FAM_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE id = " + id);
famTask.remove(position);
familyTaskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

comDBHelper.close();
```